# How to create a model with dummy coding to put into log regression

Tags: chi-squared-test, data-transformation, logit

How do I use information from a chi square table to build a statistical model. To be specific, I am using Likert-style survey information that measures student engagement. I would like to see if students with a specific intervention are more engaged than students who do not have that intervention. If they are, how does it affect their outcomes? I'm checking intervention>engagement>outcome. I do not know how to turn the results of the chi square test into a model that has new values based on salience. I will compute new variables by adding items/means together. The model will have be coded to include with the log regression measurement of the intervention which has all categorical variables.